# Pact provider jvm out of memory error in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, out-of-memory, pact

We are using pact-jvm-provider dependency for pact-verification and it is working fine on locally but I am getting below out of memory error when i run mvn test command in Jenkins pipeline.

```
Verification Failed - Uncaught exception during scan
19:52:33  
19:52:33  Failures:
19:52:33  
19:52:33  0) ItemsAssigned Event
19:52:33        Uncaught exception during scan
19:52:33  
19:52:33  [ERROR] Tests run: 7, Failures: 1, Errors: 6, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 35.366 s <<< FAILURE! - in VerifyDecanterGoodsSupplierEventContract
19:52:33  [ERROR] goods-supplier - ItemsAssigned Event  Time elapsed: 35.079 s  <<< FAILURE!
19:52:33  java.lang.AssertionError: 

19:52:33  0 - Uncaught exception during scan
19:52:33  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
19:52:33    at nonapi.io.github.classgraph.fastzipfilereader.FastZipEntry$1.<init>(FastZipEntry.java:273)
19:52:33    at nonapi.io.github.classgraph.fastzipfilereader.FastZipEntry.open(FastZipEntry.java:268)
19:52:33    at io.github.classgraph.ClasspathElementZip$1.open(ClasspathElementZip.java:300)
19:52:33    at io.github.classgraph.ClasspathElementZip$1.openOrRead(ClasspathElementZip.java:316)
19:52:33    at io.github.classgraph.Classfile.<init>(Classfile.java:1465)
19:52:33    at io.github.classgraph.Scanner$ClassfileScannerWorkUnitProcessor.processWorkUnit(Scanner.java:599)
19:52:33    at io.github.classgraph.Scanner$ClassfileScannerWorkUnitProcessor.processWorkUnit(Scanner.java:547)
19:52:33    at nonapi.io.github.classgraph.concurrency.WorkQueue.runWorkLoop(WorkQueue.java:245)
19:52:33    at nonapi.io.github.classgraph.concurrency.WorkQueue.runWorkQueue(WorkQueue.java:161)
19:52:33    at io.github.classgraph.Scanner.processWorkUnits(Scanner.java:337)
19:52:33    at io.github.classgraph.Scanner.performScan(Scanner.java:826)
19:52:33    at io.github.classgraph.Scanner.openClasspathElementsThenScan(Scanner.java:964)
19:52:33    at io.github.classgraph.Scanner.call(Scanner.java:999)
19:52:33    at io.github.classgraph.Scanner.call(Scanner.java:74)
19:52:33    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
19:52:33    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
19:52:33    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
19:52:33    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Answer (score 1):

above pact provider contract issue is reloved by applying below solution:

**Before**

I was using AmqpTarget() default constructor and it was scanning all java classes.

public final Target target = new AmqpTarget();

**After**

Now I am giving specific package name in AmqpTarget constructor

public final Target target = new AmqpTarget(Collections.singletonList("com.example.service.pact.provider.event"));

Issue is resolved now.

Comment: Good answer. I am using the `MessageTarget` from version 4.3.4 and also was having the same problem. Added the package name for the current test and it fixed the problem. Thank you for the awser!

Answer (score 0):

How much memory does Jenkins have? It looks like there is some scanning plugin (unrelated to Pact) that is running, and runs out of memory when doing so.

My guess is your laptop has more memory than Jenkins (which is possibly also running other jobs), and is under resourced.

Answer (score 0):

[`MessageTestTarget`](https://docs.pact.io/implementation_guides/jvm/provider/junit5#messagetesttarget) should be used to narrow down the scope of class scan. E.g:

```
@BeforeEach
void before(PactVerificationContext context) {
    context.setTarget(new MessageTestTarget(
         Collections.singletonList(getClass().getPackage().getName())));        
}
```